# What is the difference between new Date('"2017-12-31"') and new Date("2017-12-31")

Tags: javascript, date

I have one date string "2017-12-31"
when i pass it in `new Date("2017-12-31")` it gives the output

```
Sat Dec 30 2017 12:00:00 GMT-1200 (Local Standard Time)
```

and when i give it like `new Date('"2017-12-31"')` or `new Date("'2017-12-31'")` it gives the output

```
Sun Dec 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT-1200 (Local Standard Time)
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can anybody please explain it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue on Chrome

Comment: Whatever exactly is happening… why do you expect `Date` to correctly parse a date containing extra characters like quotes? I'd firmly put that in the category of *undefined operation*.

Comment: I get `null` with the extra quote in EDGE.

Comment: change the time zone to UTC-12

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you're passing a valid date time string in [the only format the `Date` object is required to support](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). When you do that, it's required by the spec to treat the date string you've passed it as UTC because it doesn't have a time portion (if the string had a time in it, it would be required to treat it as local time). (Sadly, this has varied a bit in the last few spec releases. It's stable now.)

In the second case, you're passing it nonsense (neither `"` nor `'` should be in a date/time string), which means an implementation can fall back to any implementation-defined mechanism for parsing the string that it wants, and it may choose to interpret it as *local* time. Apparently, your implementation is doing that (rather than the more reasonable approach — IMHO — of creating an invalid date). Since your timezone is GMT-1200, the result is that the two times are 12 hours apart.

Moral of the story: Pass only strings in the required format, or parse it yourself.